# Drop empty time based groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I use group by to group a data frame into separate days and then split them into train and test groups based on the day using concat

```
gp = dfs_0.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('B'))

train = pd.concat([ gp.get_group(group) for i,group in enumerate( gp.groups) if i < len(gp)-1 ])
test = pd.concat([ gp.get_group(group) for i,group in enumerate( gp.groups) if i == len(gp)-1 ])
```

However if the business day is a bank holdiay i have no data hence an empty group which returns an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "", line 1, in    File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py",
>   line 640, in get_group
>       raise KeyError(name) KeyError: Timestamp('2014-04-18 00:00:00', freq='B')

is there a way to filter these empty groups out pre concat

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: I try test your solution and `len(gp)-1` return always scalar - size of all groups without 1. Is it OK?

Comment: yes this is definitely fine. There are technical model based reasons i do this

Comment: jezrael i will email you some data

Comment: Super, the best some data which return problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem some no `Dates`, so get `KeyError`.

I try create custom function:

```
rng = pd.to_datetime(['2014-04-16','2014-04-17','2014-04-22 00:11:00','2014-04-22',
                      '2014-04-23','2014-04-23 10:00:03','2014-04-23 14:01:08'])
dfs_0 = pd.DataFrame({'col': range(7)}, index=rng)  
print (dfs_0)
                     col
2014-04-16 00:00:00    0
2014-04-17 00:00:00    1
2014-04-22 00:11:00    2
2014-04-22 00:00:00    3
2014-04-23 00:00:00    4
2014-04-23 10:00:03    5
2014-04-23 14:01:08    6
```

---

```
gp = dfs_0.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('B'))

def get_cust_group(g, key):
    try:
        return g.get_group(key)
    except KeyError:
        return pd.DataFrame()

#change to get_cust_group
train = pd.concat([ get_cust_group(gp,group) for i,group in enumerate( gp.groups) if i < len(gp)-1 ])
test = pd.concat([ get_cust_group(gp,group) for i,group in enumerate( gp.groups) if i == len(gp)-1 ])
print (train)
                     col
2014-04-16 00:00:00    0
2014-04-17 00:00:00    1
2014-04-22 00:00:00    3
2014-04-22 00:11:00    2

print (test)
                     col
2014-04-23 00:00:00    4
2014-04-23 10:00:03    5
2014-04-23 14:01:08    6
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to make this suggestion work.

Comment: Is possible some values are NaNs in real data?

Comment: 2014-04-17 11:59:58.465212000,5,0.009012476282633809
2014-04-22 08:00:00.207384400,-5,0.016332909547638837

Comment: and using 'B' business days adds the 18th when i use groupby

Comment: gp = dfs_0.groupby([dfs_0.index.year, dfs_0.index.month, dfs_0.index.day]) is this the best alternative

Comment: yes that works and i think my alternative works too. your might be quicker though. Thanks you have been helping me a lot recently.

Comment: Yes, but this is really complicated, sorry :(